# How to use sails-disk as session adapter in sails.js?

Tags: session, sails.js

How to use sails-disk as session adapter in sails.js?

```
module.exports.session.adapter = 'sails-disk';
```

Throws:

```
error: A hook (`session`) failed to load!
error: Could not load Connect session adapter :: sails-disk
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't use sails-disk as a session store adapter and for anything other than pre-production systems you really wouldn't want to use sails-disk full stop. The sails documentation actually goes as far as to advise against it, see [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-disk/#sails-disk-).

The good news is, out of the box sails supports Connect/Express based session stores and there are plenty of them. The most simple to setup in my experience is Redis but you can also use Mongo, Couch, Dynamo, DB2 etc.

For a complete list of Connect/Express session stores see [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores).